How to use nested navigation in The Composable Architecture using NavigationStackStore
I am working on The Composable Architecture (latest version) nested navigation. I can't figure out how can I add NavigationLink in the MoreView to take me to HistoryView. As you can see I use the NavigationStackStore.
This is the Structure:
Media -> More -> History
Media.swift:
import ComposableArchitecture
import SwiftUI

@Reducer
struct Media {
    
    @Reducer
    struct Path {
        @ObservableState
        enum State: Equatable {
            case reading(ReadingFeature.State)
            case writing(WritingFeature.State)
            case more(More.State)
        }
        enum Action {
            case reading(ReadingFeature.Action)
            case writing(WritingFeature.Action)
            case more(More.Action)
        }
        var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
            Scope(state: \.reading, action: \.reading) {
                ReadingFeature()
            }
            Scope(state: \.writing, action: \.writing) {
                WritingFeature()
            }
            Scope(state: \.more, action: \.more) {
                More()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ObservableState
    struct State: Equatable {
        var path = StackState<Path.State>()
        @Presents var destination: Destination.State?
    }
    
    enum Action {
        case appeared
        case settings
        case destination(PresentationAction<Destination.Action>)
        case path(StackAction<Path.State, Path.Action>)
    }
    
    var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
        Reduce { state, action in
            switch action {
            case .appeared:
                return .none
            case .path(_):
                return .none
            case .destination(_):
                return .none
                
            case .settings:
                state.destination = .settings(
                    SettingsFeature.State()
                )
                return .none
            }
        }
        .forEach(\.path, action: \.path) {
            Path()
        }
        .ifLet(\.$destination, action: \.destination)
    }

}

struct FrequencyMediaView: View {
    @Bindable var store: StoreOf<Media>
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationStackStore(store.scope(state: \.path, action: \.path)) {
                List {
                    Section {
                        HStack {
                            Widget(
                                header: "Planner",
                                count: 10,
                                title: "Pending",
                                image: Image(systemName: "arrowshape.down.circle.fill"))
                            
                            Widget(
                                header: "",
                                count: 12,
                                title: "Associated",
                                image: Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill"))
                            
                        }
                        .padding(0)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    
                    Section {
                        NavigationLink(
                            state: Media.Path.State.reading(ReadingFeature.State())
                        ) {
                            ButtonLabel(
                                title: "Read",
                                icon: Image(systemName: "dot.circle.fill")
                            )
                        }
                
                        NavigationLink(
                            state: Media.Path.State.writing(WritingFeature.State())
                        ) {
                            ButtonLabel(
                                title: "Record entries",
                                icon: Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil.circle.fill")
                            )
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(
                            state: Media.Path.State.more(More.State())
                        ) {
                            ButtonLabel(
                                title: "More",
                                icon: Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle.fill")
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $store.scope(
                    state: \.destination?.settings,
                    action: \.destination.settings
                )) { detailStore in
                    SettingsView(store: detailStore)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Your  setup", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading: Button(action: {
                        store.send(.settings)
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gear.circle")
                    })
                )
            } destination: { store in
                switch store.state {
                case .reading:
                    if let store = store.scope(state: \.reading, action: \.reading) {
                        ReadingView(store: store)
                    }
                case .writing:
                    if let store = store.scope(state: \.writing, action: \.writing) {
                        WritingView(store: store)
                    }
                case .more:
                    if let store = store.scope(state: \.more, action: \.more) {
                        MoreView(store: store)
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                ReadingButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Media {
    @Reducer(state: .equatable)
    enum Destination {
        case settings(SettingsFeature)
    }
}

More.swift:
import ComposableArchitecture
import SwiftUI

@Reducer
public struct More {
    
    public init() {}

    @Reducer
    public struct Path {
        @ObservableState
        
        public enum State: Equatable {
            case history(History.State)
        }
        public enum Action {
            case history(History.Action)
        }
        public var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
            Scope(state: \.history, action: \.history) {
                History()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ObservableState
    public struct State: Equatable {
        public init() {}
        
        public var path = StackState<Path.State>()
    }
    
    public enum Action {
        case appeared
        case close
        case path(StackAction<Path.State, Path.Action>)
    }
    
    public var body: some Reducer<State, Action> {
        Reduce { state, action in
            switch action {
            case .appeared:
                return .none
            case .close:
                return .none
            case .path(_):
                return .none
            }
        }
        .forEach(\.path, action: \.path) {
            Path()
        }
    }

}

public struct MoreView: View {
    public init(store: StoreOf<More>) {
        self.store = store
    }
    
    @Bindable var store: StoreOf<More>
    
    public var body: some View {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(
                        state: More.Path.State.history(History.State())
                    ) {
                        Cell(
                            title: "Record History",
                            icon: Image(systemName: "hand.raised.circle.fill")
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("More", displayMode: .inline)
            
    }
}

History.swift:
import ComposableArchitecture
import SwiftUI

@Reducer
public struct History {
    
    public init() {}

    @ObservableState
    public struct State: Equatable {
    }
    
    public enum Action {
        case appeared
    }
    
    public var body: some Reducer<State, Action> {
        Reduce { state, action in
            switch action {
            case .appeared:
                return .none
            }
        }
    }

}

public struct HistoryView: View {
    public init(store: StoreOf<History>) {
        self.store = store
    }
    
    @Bindable var store: StoreOf<History>
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text("History")
    }
}

